# C struct/function cross reference

Tags: c, function, reference, struct, param

So I'm morelikely running in a cross reference issue in C

Hello, (I couldnt write it in first for some reason)

Basicly this code:

structA.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "structB.h"

typedef struct
{
    B b;
}A;
```

structB.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "structA.h"

typedef struct
{
    int field;
}B;

void func(A* a);
```

structB.c:

```
#include "structB.h"

void func(A* a)
{
}
```

Produce the follwing errors on VC2010:

> structa.h(7): error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at
>
> least one member structa.h(7): error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>
> 'B' etc

so since I only have a pointer to A in func(A* a) I try doing a forward declaration like this:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct A;

typedef struct
{
    int field;
}B;

void func(A* a);
```

and I add #include "structA.h" in structB.c

However this doesnt work, to fix it **I have to change the param of func(A* a) to func(struct A* a) in prototype and implementation...**

But in this case i lose the purpose of typedef-ing my structs...

I know i could simply move the function to another file, but the function is related to my structure so I'd like to keep the prototype in the same file than my struct.
Now maybe thats not a good way to do thing in C, i'm mostly used to C++ so i tend to think in C++ when doing C wich is often problematic...

Does someone know a workaround? Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the issue? `func` takes a pointer to an `A`. It can be in `structA.h`. Why do you want to force it into `structB.h`? It seems like it would make more sense in `structA.h` from what you've posted. Maybe if you put the actual names instead of made-up names like `structA` and `structB` it would be more obvious what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basicly in my case, B represente a player, and func is for updatePlayer(), it takes a Game (A) pointer wich hold several useful information for updating the player, and ofc the Game struct hold a player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct structA;
```

How did this even compile? -- Correctly:

```
typedef struct A A;
```

Comment: My bad, this was a copy/paste issue, was suppose to be typedef struct A; However your correction doesnt work either: redefinition; different basic types
see declaration of 'A'

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Ok so after further researsh I've come out to the fact that it wont work if I declare my struct as this

    typedef struct
    {
    }MyStruct;

I need to declare as:


    typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
    struct MyStruct
    {
    };

And so your correction would work, H2CO3.

I didnt know that this first use of struct could lead to this kind of issue, I guess the second is cleaner.

since I cant answer my question yet, i'll mark yours as good. and sorry I cant put code blocks in comments :((, maybe you can write it for me as answer.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. You can put code blocks in comments by enclosing it into backticks: `int i = 0;`